# Correct syntax on az dls fs move?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cli

I am attempting to move some files from one directory to another in ADLS using azcli tool.

Here is my command:

```
az dls fs move --account <my dlsname> --source-path /temp/ -- 
destination-path /temp/ymd=2019-05-31/
```

Here is the error I keep getting:

```
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:

Operation failed: RENAME, temp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.64/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 206, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.64/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 560, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.64/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 618, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.64/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 611, in _run_job
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.64/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.64/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 588, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.64/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 297, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.64/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 453, in default_command_handler
    return op(**command_args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.64/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/dls/custom.py", line 251, in move_adls_item
    client.mv(source_path, destination_path)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.64/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/datalake/store/core.py", line 536, in mv
    destination=path2.as_posix())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.64/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/datalake/store/lib.py", line 458, in call
    self.log_response_and_raise(response, err)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.64/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/datalake/store/lib.py", line 344, in log_response_and_raise
    raise exception
azure.datalake.store.exceptions.DatalakeRESTException: Operation failed: RENAME, temp
```

The documentation on this is very slim as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/dls/fs?view=azure-cli-latest#az-dls-fs-move

I get this for a number of variations on this command. I must be missing something on the syntax here.

Comment: Was able to reproduce the issue and created a GitHub issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9729 to track and pursue it with Product team, will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

@Josh,

I have tried the same code and it worked for me , i have tried both variant for the move command:

[image]

Here are the command precisely:

```
az login
az account set --subscription 'subscriptionid'
# move the complete folder    
az dls fs move --account 'accountName'--destination-path '/mvdest' --source-path '/destination'    
#move the file    
az dls fs move --account 'accountName'--destination-path '/destination/test.txt' --source-path '/source/test.txt'
```

Here is the output for the same:

[image]

Make sure you have the right set of privilege before using this command.

Hope it helps.